# Connected components and arcwise connected components

Tags: general-topology

Could someone give me an example of a topological space such that the number of connected components does not match with the number of pathwise (arcwise) connected components

Thanks

Comment: Topologist's Sine Curve is such an example

Comment: Thanks mate, now I remember that I saw it in Patty´s topology books

Answer (score 1):

(*To make it answered*)

@Clayton comment:

> The topologist's Sine Curve is such an example.